# Create file from image url getting exception android

Tags: android, fileutils

I am trying to create file from facebook profile picture url but its getting FileNotFoundException.
My code is like-

```
    URL url = null;
    File file = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(IMAGE_URL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String tDir = System.getProperty("‌​java.io.tmpdir");
    String path = tDir + "tmp" + ".jpg";
    file = new File(path);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I have done wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not aware that Android supports `"‌​java.io.tmpdir"`, and Android does not have a `FileUtils` class.

Comment: what should I change to make it work? any other solution? I need to create file without downloading.

Comment: Have you checked your file path ?

Comment: "I need to create file without downloading" -- by definition, creating a file with the contents of an image from the Internet is "downloading". You are welcome to write your file to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), or possibly [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

MAke sure you have the necessary permissions for writing and reading file storage in your Manifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```